# Change my Azure subscription Tenant ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, bizspark

Following article describe how to move resources between Azure subscriptions.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

However it says that both subscriptions must exist within the same tenant. Apparently that is not the case with my 2 Azure accounts and I didn't know until now that behind the scenes I have a Tenant ID linked to these accounts.

I'm now wondering how to get some of my accounts that I'm using for my company to be linked to a common Tenant ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer for the new portal (early 2018).

Follow this link: [How to associate or add an Azure subscription to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory) to associate your subscription with the new tenant (directory).

Once you've done it, you can transfer between subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Tenant here refers to Azure Active Directory (AAD) associated with your azure subscription.

The steps to change the associated AAD for an Azure subscription are described [here](http://rickrainey.com/windows-azure-how-tos/how-to-change-the-directory-associated-with-your-windows-azure-subscription/).

The service admin of the Azure subscription, who is already a member of the current associated AAD, should also be member in AAD you want to associate.

Typically, existing AAD belongs to a Microsoft account. This accounts needs to be added to the target AAD.

Comment: Down voted for the following reasons: 1. The linked steps no longer work. 2. Please don't paste answers that just link to somewhere else; provide the actual steps inline. (Links break, etc.)